Kong Gateway: I got an error when I run docker-compose up
Create the kong-gateway container using docker compose, got an error as follow:
[lua] globalpatches.lua:84: sleep(): executing a blocking 'sleep' (0.004 seconds), context: init_worker_by_lua*
[lua] globalpatches.lua:84: sleep(): executing a blocking 'sleep' (0.002 seconds), context: init_worker_by_lua*
[lua] globalpatches.lua:84: sleep(): executing a blocking 'sleep' (0.016 seconds), context: init_worker_by_lua*
[lua] globalpatches.lua:84: sleep(): executing a blocking 'sleep' (0.008 seconds), context: init_worker_by_lua*
[lua] warmup.lua:53: warming up DNS entries ..., context: ngx.timer
[lua] warmup.lua:87: finished warming up DNS entries' into the cache (in 39ms), context: ngx.timer;

The kong-gateway command in docker compose file:

services:
  networks:
    backend:

  postgres:
     ....
     ....
     ....

  kong:
    image: kong/kong-gateway
    platform: linux/amd64
    environment:
      - KONG_DATABASE=postgres
      - KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout
      - KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout
      - KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr
      - KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr
      - KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN="0.0.0.0:8001, 0.0.0.0:8444 ssl"
      - KONG_PG_HOST=postgres
      - KONG_PG_USER=postgres
      - KONG_PG_PASSWORD=postgres
      - KONG_CASSANDRA_CONTACT_POINTS=postgres
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 8001:8001
      - 8002:8002
      - 8443:8443
      - 8444:8444
    command:
      - kong
      - start
      - --vv
    restart: no
    networks:
      - backend

But there is no issue when creating the container directly using docker run command:
      docker run \
         -d \
         --platform=linux/amd64 \
         --name kong \
         --network=test_backend \
         -e "KONG_DATABASE=postgres" \
         -e "KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout" \
         -e "KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout" \
         -e "KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr" \
         -e "KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr" \
         -e "KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8001, 0.0.0.0:8444 ssl" \
         -e "KONG_PG_HOST=postgres" \
         -e "KONG_PG_USER=postgres" \
         -e "KONG_PG_PASSWORD=postgres" \
         -e "KONG_CASSANDRA_CONTACT_POINTS=postgres" \
         -p 8000:8000 \
         -p 8001:8001 \
         -p 8002:8002 \
         -p 8443:8443 \
         -p 8444:8444 \
         kong/kong-gateway

There is no issue with the Postgres container, and also the kong migrations (kong bootstrap).
I created the 'kong' database manually in Postgres without any issue.
After that manually run the kong migration using docker run, also no issue with this.

You run command does not include command, unlike the docker compose fragment.

That doesn't seem to be an error, but a notice (globalpatches.lua), and as @AlexanderMashin said, you didn't include kong start in the docker run command

@AlexanderMashin i understand, i fixed it

@mikyll98, thank you
